# Let $I$ be a left ideal of a ring $R$. Prove that if $I$ is a direct summand then $I^2=I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $I$ be a left ideal of a ring $R$ with $1$. Prove that if $I$ is a direct
>   summand then $I^2=I$.

**Definition.** An ideal $A$ is a direct summand of a ring $R$ iff there exists an ideal $B$ of $R$ such that $R=A\oplus B$

Help me.

Comment: What does it mean when you can write two ideals as $A\oplus B$?

Comment: It's direct sum

Comment: Is $R$ unital?​

Comment: Yes, $R$ is a ring with $1$

Comment: If $R=I\oplus J$, the key is to decompose $1=e+e'$ with $e\in I,e'\in J$. Do you see the role $e$ plays as an element of $I$?

Comment: Can you explain more precise?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the ideal $I$ is a direct summand of $R$, then there is an ideal $J$ with $R=I\oplus J$, with $I \cap J = 0$. Put $1= e + f$, with $e \in I$ and $f \in J$. Then, $e=e\cdot 1=e(e+f)=e^2+ef$. Since $ef \in I \cap J$, $ef=0$, and hence $e$ is an *idempotent*, that is $e^2=e$ (and likewise $f^2=f$). Of course $I^2 \subseteq I$. If $r \in I$, then $r=r\cdot1=r\cdot(e+f)=re \in I^2$.

Comment: maybe another mention of why $rf=0$ would be appropriate (of course it's the same reason as why $ef=0$.)

Comment: Dustan, sure, but user110834 should also learn something from this!

Comment: No need to use elements. $I = IR \subseteq II + IJ = I^2$ since $IJ \subseteq I \cap J = 0$.

Comment: @NickyHekster: Thank you very much. And I want to know: Does exist a ring with $I^2=I$ but $I$ is not a direct summand?

Comment: Good question! The following is true: if $I$ is a *minimal* ideal in a unital ring with $I^2=I$, then it is a direct summand! So for the counterexample, the idempotent ideal $I$ must not be minimal. Will come back to that

Comment: @user110834 I agree that it is a good question. It is sufficient to find an idempotent ideal which does not take the form $Rx$ i.e. we want one which is not generated by an idempotent element.

Comment: There may even be a commutative example. Exercise 2.1 of Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory says that if $I$ is *finitely generated* and $I=I^2$, then $I=(e)$. **Edit.** How about this: $R=\mathbb Q[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots]/(x_1^2-x_1,\dots)$ and $I=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$.

Comment: Karl, yes this is an excellent example! +1 Thanks!

Comment: "Since $ef\in I\cap J$..." It's certainly in $J$, but you'll need to convince people it's in $I$ :) It looks to me like you're assuming the ideals are two-sided, or that the ring is commutative, but the OP is explicitly talking about a left ideal.

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg : *"since $IJ\subseteq I\cap J=0$"* For sure this containment works for two-sided ideals, but the OP specified left ideals. In $R=M_2(F)$, with $I=RE_{11}$ and $J=RE_{22}$, $I\cap J=0$ and yet $IJ=J$. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb I felt uneasy about this too, and I would have raised this concern had Nicky Hekster not preceeded the claim with the equation $e=e^2+ef$ which implies $ef\in I$.

Comment: Guys, you are perfectly right there should be emphasis on left ideal vs two-sided. Thanks @rschwieb. After all we have a good discussion here!!

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Yeah I guess that's right: the example I gave did not satisfy the $e+f=1$ part :)

Answer (score 7):

One good thing to learn from this is that for rings with identity, left (or right) ideals are summands iff they are generated by an idempotent.

Here's a sketch:

With $R=I\oplus J$, write $1=e+f$ in this decomposition. Multiplying on the left by $e$, we discover $e=e^2+ef\in I\oplus J$. But $e$ is uniquely expressed already as $e+0$, so $e=e^2$.

We claim that $I=Re$. If $i\in I$, then $i=ie+if$, but because $i$ is already uniquely expressed as $i+0$ in the sum, we have that $if=0$ and $ie=i$. So, $I\subseteq Re$. Conversely, $e\in I$ so $Re\subseteq I$.

This makes proving $I^2=I$ a breeze: obviously $I^2\subseteq I$ so the other containment is the only thing to prove. But $e=e^2\in I^2$, therefore $I=Re\subseteq I^2$.